# Multipart/Realted API request in POSTMAN

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-native-app

I need to know the setup process of multipart/related  file upload API request in POSTMAN.

I have the following details

API url :- https://apiq-jmqny-ste.azpre-api.net

json body :- {
"token" : "aqop094567",
"flow" : "work"
}

pdf file :- Pt_003.pdf

Boundary value :- Acb067

Please anyone suggest some solution regarding that.

Answer (score 0):

At the End of the Key there is small dropdown to select to File where you can upload Files as shown below May be this can help

[image: You Can try the Form Data in postman]